# Does the Search field on the launcher in kde depend on Nepomuk?

Tags: launcher, kde4, plasma, nepomuk

Does the search field on the application launcher depend on Nepomuk?

I had to disable Nepomuk on shared systems because it takes too much CPU and I/O and I have noticed that on some systems the search field for programs does not show newly installed programs. Does that function depend on Nepomuk file indexing?

Answer (score 1):

**By my knowledge**

By my knowledge the KDE is using the kbuildsycoca4 to build the KDE menu cache. The launchers are then using the cache to search and launch the programs.

Searching...'update kde menu' -> https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=64514

If the KDE menu is not updating automatically you could try to run the kbuildsycoca4 from the Konsole.

```
:~$ kbuildsycoca4 --help
Usage: kbuildsycoca4 [Qt-options] [KDE-options] [options] 

Rebuilds the system configuration cache.

Generic options:
  --help                    Show help about options
  --help-qt                 Show Qt specific options
  --help-kde                Show KDE specific options
  --help-all                Show all options
  --author                  Show author information
  -v, --version             Show version information
  --license                 Show license information
  --                        End of options

Options:
  --nosignal                Do not signal applications to update
  --noincremental           Disable incremental update, re-read everything
  --checkstamps             Check file timestamps
  --nocheckfiles            Disable checking files (dangerous)
  --global                  Create global database
  --menutest                Perform menu generation test run only
  --track <menu-id>         Track menu id for debug purposes
```

**Launchers**

The KDE has plenty of launchers: http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?59851-KDE-Application-Launchers .

The Mangonel advertise:

> Mangonel, a simple application launcher for KDE4.
>
> Mangonel is intended as a light weight replacement for the, in my
>   view bloated and slow, standard KRunner...

The Mangonel is available from the Ubuntu repositories: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=mangonel&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all