# Keyboard navigation in KDE menu stops working randomly

Tags: keyboard, kde

Sometimes, probably after last ubuntu upgrade, my keyboard doesn't work in this particular input:

[image]

I can paste, but I can't type. Keyboard works everywhere else. Sometimes it works even in menu, but mostly doesn't. How can I fix this? (I also can't take exact screenshot of KDE search/menu, because PrintScreen button closes menu and makes wrong screenshot of everything else, so I am using typical picture from the net here.)

This is my KDE version:

[image]

Comment: Not sure if related, but it can freeze it. Try rebuild the cache using: `kbuildsycoca4 --noincremental` then logout/login. Based on info from https://askubuntu.com/a/293129/26246